# How to use the Video controller output (backup) while also using the video card output

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

So, I have been trying to restore an extremely old computer (pavilion a 750y, Pentium 520 processor) to working order by installing a WIFI card, new ram etc. In the process of doing this I discovered that the computer had a second VGA out that could be used if the main graphics card was not connected( the video controller out); and yet I cannot seem to use this output while the video card is attached. The computer does not even seem to recognize that the second output exists, even though it theoretically can be used.

Is there a way to run two monitors on this computer, or is the second video out an absolute last resort that the computer will only use if there is not graphics card?

Comment: Check BIOS for a setting related to "integrated video card."

Comment: The Bios seems to allow me to choose which monitor I use, but as far as I can see, there is no setting that allows both to be used